# See list of users by bounty reputation earned/spent

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, data-explorer, statistics

Is there a way (I expect through the data explorer) to see a list of users in descending order based solely on the amount of reputation they have earned through bounties?

Conversely, how about the same sort of list based on the amount of reputation points spent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total points spent: [Total bounty amount offered by user](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/208751/total-bounty-amount-offered-by-user).

Total points earned: [Top 200 Bounty Earners](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/158342/top-200-bounty-earners).